# How is this CSS class working when it is not listed anywhere?

Tags: css, templates, dreamweaver

I opened Adobe Dreamweaver's Starter Template named 'Email-Fluid' and everything seems pretty straight forward other than there are some CSS classes that are being used but i can't locate the styles for them.
So for instance there is the following line of code:-

```
`<div style="display:inline-block; max-width:50%; margin: 0 -2px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;" class="stack-column">`
```

You will see that there is a class defined as 'stack-column' however this class cannot be found within the header of the document.  There is also no links to outside documents or calls to Bootstrap.

In addition there are tags (that i think are HTML) that i don't recognise like `<webversion>` and `<unsubscribe>`.

Can anyone help me understand what these are so that i can edit the classes?